# GCP CLOUD SQL denies permission for pre aggregation

Tags: cube.js

I am trying to use pre aggregations over CLOUD SQL on Google Cloud Platform but the database is denying access and giving error Statement violates GTID consistency.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Cube.js done pre-aggregation by `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`, but you are using MySQL on top of Google SQL with `--enforce-gtid-consistency` (has limitations).

Since only transactionally safe statements can be logged, there is a limitation to use `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` (and some another SQL), because this statement is actually logged as two separate events.

There are two ways how to solve this issue:

#### 1. Use pre-aggregations to an external database. (recommended way).

https://cube.dev/docs/pre-aggregations/#read-only-data-source-pre-aggregations

#### 2. Use not documented flag `loadPreAggregationWithoutMetaLock`

**Attention: This flag is an experimental and can be removed or changed in the feature.**.

[Take a look at the source code](https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js/blob/v0.20.9/packages/cubejs-mysql-driver/driver/MySqlDriver.js#L131)

You can pass it directly in the driver constructor. This will produce two SQL statements to pass the limitation:

- `CREATE TABLE`
- `INSERT INTO`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so we are going with AWS RDS since it doesn't have the enforce-gtid-consistency policy.